# How to handle the drop downs with no ul and li

Tags: java, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i6xm.jpg)

aria-activedescendant value keep changing depending on mouse hover.
Unable to get all the elements values

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please provide the webpage snapshot. in your screenshot we are not seeing any ul or li